# Utilizar comando cls de .bat em Linguagem Java

Tags: java, bat

Estou com um código para iniciar uma sessão no Putty, com o IP referente a um equipamento de cada cidade.
Dentro do código em java, eu faço o uso de comandos .bat, como por exemplo o uso do comando |CLIP e o start putty.

Porém, como tenho um Menu dentro de um WHILE, esse menu acaba poluindo a tela cada vez que o `while` se repete.
Portanto, pensei em apensar usar código:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cls");
```

Porém, não funciona, não limpa a tela, porém não dá erro. É como se o código ignorasse a linha do `cls`.

Alguém saberia informar como deve ser feito esse clear na tela?

Esse código vai ser usado pelo setor de redes da empresa, então eu realmente preciso entregar uma coisa mais "limpa" para usarem.

```
while(menu == 1){                              
    
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    System.out.println("Teófilo Otoni OLT 6 ---> teo6");
    System.out.println("Teófilo Otoni OLT 7 ---> teo7");
    System.out.println("Caravelas -------------> car");
    System.out.println("Cidade Nobre ----------> cid");
    System.out.println("Manhuaçu --------------> man");
    System.out.println("Santana do Paraíso ----> par");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("OLT [APENAS OS 3 PRIMEIROS DÍGITOS]: ");
    olt = entrada.next();

    if(!"teo6".equals(olt) && !"teo7".equals(olt)  && !"car".equals(olt) && !"cid".equals(olt)  && !"man".equals(olt) && !"par".equals(olt) && !"san".equals(olt) ){
        System.out.println("##### OLT INVÁLIDA #####\n\n");
        
    }else{
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c cls");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c echo "+sn+"| clip");
        System.out.println("S/N: ");   
        sn = entrada.next();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Esta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33379766) explica porque sua abordagem não funciona, mas basicamente [`Runtime.exec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File)) redireciona a saída padrão para um *pipe* que pode ser lido pelo processo Java. Como a saída foi redirecionada, esta não é aplicada ao console, e por isso ele não limpa a tela do mesmo.

A mesma resposta dá a solução: invocar o comando com um [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) e conectar a saída do comando com a saída do processo Java, usando [`inheritIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) (método disponível a partir do JDK 7):

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
```

Assim, quando o programa for iniciado em um console pela linha de comando, a tela será limpa.

Comment: Cara, funcionou perfeitamente!!!
Muito obrigado! Estava atrás da solução há algum tempo. 
Obrigado mesmo.